# Element positioning CSS

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

I am adding new `span` elements to a `div` element (using .append) of fixed size. When I add many elements the 'div' overflows with a scroll bar. Is it possible to prevent this and wrap all the elements inside the `div` to display in a tabular format?

A sample of what I am trying is at http://jsfiddle.net/Hj3Qe/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
#x{
    word-wrap:break-word;
}​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Hj3Qe/3/)**.

This will keep the spans within the div's width, although I'm not sure what you're looking for with a tabular format without using tables. For that you may want to add the CSS rule of     `display:inline-block;` to your spans, adjusting the width as needed.

**[jsFiddle example #2](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Hj3Qe/4/)**.

```
span {
    width:20px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: The 2nd example looks awesome.. By tabular format I meant viewing in a orderly way.

Comment: Other interesting stuff I noted is when I used word-wrap the `<span>` elements overlapped one above the other.. Can this be due to any css applied on the div ? Also does having a charater '-' affect line breaks? (If I have a '-' in a span element, the element breaks and all others continue from the next line..)
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/Hj3Qe/5/) . In this example, 6 break before '-' !

Comment: This is the only mention I could find about the way the break-word functions: An unbreakable "word" may be broken at an arbitrary point if there are no otherwise-acceptable break points in the line. Shaping characters are still shaped as if the word were not broken, and grapheme clusters must together stay as one unit. No hyphenation character is inserted at the break point.